# Location / path of phpunit.xml

Tags: linux, phpunit

Where the `phpunit.xml` configuration file of PHPUNIT test framework is located on linux server, please?

I can't google this information anywhere..

Comment: At last there is something google can't find!

Comment: The documentation does explain the syntax for the file, but not where to put it. Also kind of weird that you can't have a system-wide config file for PHPUnit even to define project-independent settings, such as always --coloring the output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

let's assume you use ubuntu, but this should not change much:

you can put it anywhere you want and use the following switch to use 'your' config:

```
  --configuration <file>
              Read configuration from XML file.
```

see: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/raring/en/man1/phpunit.1.html

Comment: thanks, I was thinking that phpunit.xml exists somewhere by default.

Comment: Apparently PHPUnit does search by default for a phpunit.xml in the project root. I'm basing this on own experience and [documentation provided by JetBrains for PhpStorm](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/using-phpunit-framework.html#php_test_frameworks_phpunit_integrate) - quote: 

`By default, PHPUnit looks for a phpunit.xml or phpunit.xml.dist configuration file in the project root folder. You can appoint a custom configuration file.`